# Getting variable of requesting host Apache htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have the below code, that I can use the below to set a variable:

```
SetEnvIf Host (.*) custom_host=$1
```

What I want is a variable of the requesting host/computer.

For example, if the website `http://example.com:32/welcome` is making the request, I want this as the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Host` you need `Referer` to access the HTTP `Referer` header that is sent in the request. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Referer (.*) custom_referer=$1
```

However, depending on the server-side scripting language you are using, you rarely need to assign this to another variable. You can usually reference it directly as required.

Also note, the HTTP `Referer` header might not be set. The referring site and the user's browser can both block this.

**UPDATE:**

> how can i have just the protocol, domain and host without the path.

Try changing the regex to something like:

```
SetEnvIf Referer ^(https?://[^/]+) custom_referer=$1
```

If the `Referer` is `http://example.com:32/welcome`, then this should result in just `http://example.com:32` being stored in the `custom_referer` variable.

Comment: that works, however i realised the CORS match fails because it has the path in there as well, how can i have just the protocol, domain and host without the path.

Comment: can you please adjust this answer to remove the trailing slash, then it should work